# How to gather information on Input touches outside event handlers

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, touch

I have an app in UWP that should perform complex gestures, responding to pen, mouse and (multiple) touch events.

I need an easy way to detect at a certain point in time the status of each pointer that is touching the screen: is there an UWP API that I can query to retrieve how many and which pointers are currently touching the screen?

I am trying to take care of this state by myself, but it is very complex due to the events that are firing in apparently non-deterministic way.

For instance, I have a ScrollViewer where I put a finger down, and I receive the `PointerPressed` (and sometimes few `PointerMoved`) event. This is OK.
Then, I put a second finger down: I receive the `PointerPressed` (and sometimes few `PointerMoved`) event also for the second pointer (absolutely correct), but also a PointerCaptureLost from the first finger!!

Please note that apparently this behavior comes out only with ScrollViewers, not with e.g. Canvas.

If I can query the UWP framework to have the stable truth, it will simplify heavily my job.

Here's an MVCE to check the behavior that I am presenting.
https://github.com/cghersi/UWPExamples/tree/master/MultipleTouches

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and you get the current Pointer via `e.GetCurrentPoint()`.

But if multiple input sources, `GetCurrentPointer` can only get the latest input, this seems to be the cause of your confusion.

Try using `e.GetIntermediatePoints()` to get all the pointers on the control. This method can meet your needs.

This method returns the history of the pointer event. You can use the `pointer.PointerDevice` to determine the input source. You can use `pointer.Properties.IsCanceled` to determine whether the event is valid.

For more information about the PointerPoint class, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint).

Best regards.

Comment: Hi Richasy, I tried your approach with  e.GetIntermediatePoints() but unfortunately this returns only the info regarding one pointer type (i.e. the returning list of PointerPoint has elements with the same PointerId...). I need instead something that gives me the status of ALL the pointers (e.g. if I have 2 fingers on the screen, I want 2 PointerPoint with different PointerId...)

Comment: I am sorry, Microsoft said `Manipulations should not be distinguished by the number of fingers used.` in the document. So, there is no direct method for judging the number of fingers in UWP. I suggest you use the interactive logic of "gesture", you can judge by events such as `ManipulationStarted`, please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#custom-touch-interactions). I am sorry, but if you must get the number of fingers, then recording every `PointerPressed` event is almost the only way.

Comment: Thanks @Richasy, I was afraid of this answer :( The problem is that the PointerPressed doesn't correspond to a PointerReleased, it could also be a PointerLost, so it is quite a mess. Plus, I don't get why the ScrollViewer issues a PointerCaptureLost while I still have both my fingers on the screen...

Comment: Hi, A pointer does not mean a single finger/mouse, it is more like an event, a two-finger touch is a pointer, and a one-finger touch is another. When you change from one finger to two fingers, there is no superposition of Pointer, but it becomes another kind of Pointer, which may be the cause of the loss.